# Defining a method where it's used

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on some Fast.ai deep learning and I need to save my model, but it uses a method which I don't want to have to bring.

So what I need is how to define a method where it is needed, which I am pretty sure I've seen somewhere but I don't remember what it's called as I try to show in the code below.

```
dblock = DataBlock(blocks=(ImageBlock, MultiCategoryBlock),
                splitter=RandomSplitter(seed=42),
                get_items=get_image_files,
                get_y= def get_y(r) : [return parent_label(r)],
                item_tfms=Resize(460),
                batch_tfms=aug_transforms(size=224, min_scale=0.75))
```

Comment: Are you talking about `lambda` syntax…?! `lambda r: parent_label(r)` But really, this would be the same as just `parent_label` here.

Comment: @deceze I might be thinking about lambda. I thought I had seen a method definition like mine somwhere, but I might be misstaken.

Comment: @deceze the lambda works, I just needed it to return the result of parent_label as a list so i changed it to    lambda r: [parent_label(r),]